# Upload shaplfile ( tif ) to PostgreSQL/PostGIS using PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, postgis

I need to import my file ( .tif ) to my BD ( postgres ) via web interface.

I use this code but it doesn't work:

```
<body>
  <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <label for="fichier">Ajouter raster :</label><br />
     <input type="file" name="fichier"  />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoyer" />
</form>
<?php    { $db = pg_connect('host=5432 dbname=gisdb user=postges    password=ou$$am@16'); 

        $raster = pg_escape_string($_POST['fichier']); 
        $name = $_FILES['$raster']['name']; 

        $query = "INSERT INTO eau_param_hydro(rast,filname) VALUES('". addslashes($raster) ."','" . $name . "')"; 
        $result = pg_query($query); 
        if (!$result) { 
            $errormessage = pg_last_error(); 
            echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage; 
            exit(); 
        } 
        pg_close(); }
        ?> 

  </body>
```

Comment: what mean `doesnt work` any error?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: btw not sure if you can insert a raster like that, you probably need use a tool [**raster2pgsql**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65848/loading-raster-data-to-postgis)

Comment: thanks , I don't have any error but the file is not added

Comment: Not familiar with PHP, but know you have to set something to trap the error. otherwise will be ignored.

Comment: the method to import shapfile to postgis via web onterface  it's the right one ?

Comment: I dont know all. But I guess not, you probably have to save the file on your server and call the raster2pgsql tool.